# Как такое записать в PHP?

Tags: php

делаю мультиязычный сайт на Drupal 7,есть кусок кода

$output .= '<div class="tours">';

$ln == 'en' ? $day = 'Day Tour ' : $day = 'Дневной тур';

$output .= drupal_render($form['field_tours']['und'][]);

$output .= drupal_render($form['field_tours']['und']['Night Tour']);

$output .= drupal_render($form['field_tours']['und']['Custom Tour']);

$output .= '</div>';

Который означает,что если язык английский то выводим Day Tour,иначе выводим Дневной тур  итак далее.
Вопрос в том,как вставить $day в скобку?( $output .= drupal_render($form['field_tours']['und'][здесь должна быть $day]);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> как вставить $day в скобку?

Надо просто вставить $day *в скобку*

```
$form['field_tours']['und'][$day]
```

неожиданность / паранормальное

Comment: я только начал изучать PHP,а как это будет в моем случае?

Comment: ровно как написано выше

Comment: написал так
  $output .= '<div class="tours">';
  $ln == 'en' ? $day = 'Day Tour ' : $day = 'Дневной тур';
  $form['field_tours']['und'][$day];
  $output .= '</div>';
  
Ничего не выводит(

Comment: @Руслан Сабанов, вы забыли значение из массива в переменную $output записать:

   $output .= $form['field_tours']['und'][$day];

Comment: записал так

$output .= '<div class="tours">';

$ln == 'en' ? $day = 'Day Tour ' : $day = 'Дневной тур';

$output .= $form['field_tours']['und'][$day];

$output .= '</div>';

выдает ошибку Notice: Undefined index: Day Tour in theme_custom_form_theme_function()

Comment: @Руслан Сабанов, PHP сообщает, что нет такого индекса в массиве, т.е. $form['field_tours']['und']['Day Tour'] не существует. Чтобы посмотреть, что вообще есть в массиве, можете его вывести через print_r(), например, так:

    $output .= print_r($form, true);